# Did these have to be merged?

Tags: discussion, merged-questions

There is [a Question asking for a recommendation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5477/tumblr-vs-posterous) and another [asking for comprehensive differences](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/what-are-differences-between-tumblr-and-posterous). Are these so similar that they had to be merged? [Look here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) too.

Answer (score 4):

They should both be closed as "Do some product comparison work for me" type questions.

Off-topic or Not a real question - take your pick.

What's the problem that needs to be solved in either case? Reading them both it comes off as trying to work out which product is better than the other. "Help me decide!" and all that.

Slap a dollar sign on each of those services and you've gone shopping.

Comment: And... what's wrong with "Help me decide!"?

Comment: They often end up being shopping type questions and too localised to what the OP is feeling peckish for at the time. Not something that helps others really @tsh

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with these 2 questions necessarily, but a good answer on a question asking for a recommendation between 2 products will compare the differences.

Comment: *Which between service A and service B should I take if I wanted feature X?* __versus__ *Gimme the differences between service A and service B*. The first will focus more on feature X.