# How and whether to use tag [merging]?

Tags: discussion, tags

**Update**: Tag no longer exists.

---

There are presently two Open Qs tagged [merging](/questions/tagged/merging):

[Did these have to be merged?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/768/did-these-have-to-be-merged)

[Duplicate user created?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/809/duplicate-user-created)

One concerns merging questions (specifically two that have since been deleted) and the other user accounts (for a specific user).

In general, where a tag is applied to two different questions it will not automatically be deleted (each causes the other to be maintained). However it seems that even a single instance may not automatically be deleted when used for WAmeta.

Another, and more popular use, for “merging” is in connection with tags, though in that sense we have [tag-request](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-request) whose Usage guide is at present:

> This tag is for requests to replace one tag with another existing tag. It also applies to requests that one tag should be merged into another, or simply abandoned.

Possibly related:

[user-accounts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-accounts) whose Usage guide at present is:

> Refers to user accounts either generically, or across the network.

[login](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/login) whose Usage guide at present is:

> For issues connected with site access to Web Applications as a registered user.

and, perhaps, without Usage guides at present:

[account-association](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-association)
[users](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users)
[user-profiles](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-profiles)

If [merging](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merging) is to be retained, should it apply to both “accounts” and “questions”, and if not, to which, or to neither?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) for guidance, they have separate tags for [`merge-accounts`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merge-accounts) and [`merged-questions`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merged-questions).

---

I've created [merge-accounts](/questions/tagged/merge-accounts) and [merged-questions](/questions/tagged/merged-questions) and created tag wikis for each.

Comment: Sure, for future questions. Ambiguous tags aren't useful, even their only on a couple of questions.

Comment: I've already done it.